# How to give different values to a git command and store the output in several files for each value?

Tags: git, bash, shell, github, git-bash

I'm trying to generate a JSON file for each diff commit I got on my GitHub.
In order to do that I store my "SHA" number in a variable like this:

```
$var=$(git log --pretty=format:'%h')
```

then I want to do a for loop, where I say for each value stored in var execute the command git show and store the output in a file for example ( commit1.json .... Commit100.json etc..) ( `git show $var > Commits.json`)

I'm a newbie in the shell, so I have no idea how to make that happen.
Please guys I'm really counting on your help.

How do I get rid of special characters when I generate my files: revision_2017-03-20T140150+0100

Because later I'm trying to open them and parse through them and because of the special characters I can't open them.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git log --pretty=format:'%h' | while read revision; do git show $revision > revision_"$revision".json; done`

If you wanted to use something else (like author date) to name the file, you could do something like this:

`git log --pretty=format:'%h' | while read revision
    do date=$( git show --summary --pretty=%aI $revision | head -n 1)
    git show $revision > revision_"$date".json
done`

Comment: Thank you for your answer this is working pretty good. But I want to have the content of each commit in a different json file. Not all of them in one? 

For each value of $var where I have all my SHA generate a json file 

git show var[1]  >> commit1.json
git show var[100] >> commit100.json
;
..

.
.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Corrected on the original response

Comment: Hey again! Can I get the date and the hour of the generation of the commit as a name of the json file instead of getting "revision and sha" as the name of the file 

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess inside the while loop you could do a run of ```git show --pretty=%ai``` to get that information in a variable so you can use it to name the file. Let me add it to the original response.

Comment: Question : how do I get rid of special carracters, when I generate my  files  : revision_2017-03-20T140150+0100

Comment: I guess you have to play a little bit with the date options in --pretty when you set $date.